# Give subnets in a list and access them using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, subnet

I am giving the subnets one by one, I want to give it in a list but I am confused if I did how will I be able to access the specific subnets from the list.I want to do the same with availability zone. Like if I want to give `public_subnet_cidr_2` how would I give it if it is in the list.

main.tf

```
module "my_vpc" {
  source   = "./modules/vpc"
  vpc_cidr = "13.0.0.0/16"
  #tenancy               = "default"
  vpc_id                = "${module.my_vpc.vpc_id}"
  public_subnet_cidr_1  = "13.0.1.0/24"
  public_subnet_cidr_2  = "13.0.2.0/24"
  private_subnet_cidr_1 = "13.0.3.0/24"
  private_subnet_cidr_2 = "13.0.4.0/24"
  availability_zone_1   = "us-east-2a"
  availability_zone_2   = "us-east-2b"
}
```

vpc-main.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
  tags = {
    Name = "wahaj-vpc"
  }
}

# Define the public subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id     = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_cidr_1

  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_1

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet 1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id     = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_cidr_2

  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_2

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet 2"
  }
}

# Define the private subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = var.private_subnet_cidr_1
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_1

  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet 1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = var.private_subnet_cidr_2
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_2

  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet 2"
  }
}
# Define the internet gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "VPC IGW"
  }
}

# Define the route table
resource "aws_route_table" "web_public_rt" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet RT"
  }
}

# Assign the route table to the public Subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "web-public-rt" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.web_public_rt.id
}
```

Comment: Hi. Just wonder how did it go with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are **several apparent issues** in your code:

- You can't have VPC with CIDR of `13.0.0.0/16`. I guess it should be  `10.0.0.0/16`.
- Its also a very unusually way of creating VPC with `aws_vpc` being outside of the module.
- The module is also missing `public_subnet_1`.
- Better to use list as variables, rather then passing individual `public_subnet_cidr_1`, `public_subnet_cidr_2` and so on.
- I don't see a reason why you would need to hardcore `availability_zone_1` and `availability_zone_2`. Better to use `data` source for that.

Anyway, I **modified** your files, so that they deploy. I **verified** that in `us-east-1` region in my sandbox account. Please note, I only made it to deploy with **minimal changes to your code**. I **haven't verified** if the VPC is functioning nor whether it works as intend.

**main.tf**

```
provider "aws" {
  # your data
}

resource "aws_vpc" "main" {
  cidr_block       = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}


module "my_vpc" {
  source   = "./modules/vpc"
  vpc_cidr = "10.0.0.0/16"
  vpc_id                = aws_vpc.main.id
  public_subnet_cidr_1  = "10.0.1.0/24"
  public_subnet_cidr_2  = "10.0.2.0/24"
  private_subnet_cidr_1 = "10.0.3.0/24"
  private_subnet_cidr_2 = "10.0.4.0/24"
  availability_zone_1   = "us-east-1a"
  availability_zone_2   = "us-east-1b"
}
```

**module/vpc/vpc.tf**

```
variable "vpc_id" {}
variable "vpc_cidr" {}
variable "public_subnet_cidr_1" {}
variable "public_subnet_cidr_2" {}
variable "private_subnet_cidr_1" {}
variable "private_subnet_cidr_2" {}
variable "availability_zone_1" {}
variable "availability_zone_2" {}


resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id     = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_cidr_1

  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_1

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet 1"
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "public_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id     = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block = var.public_subnet_cidr_2

  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_2

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet 2"
  }
}

# Define the private subnet
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_1" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = var.private_subnet_cidr_1
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_1

  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet 1"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet_2" {
  vpc_id            = var.vpc_id
  cidr_block        = var.private_subnet_cidr_2
  availability_zone = var.availability_zone_2

  tags = {
    Name = "Private Subnet 2"
  }
}
# Define the internet gateway
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "gw" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "VPC IGW"
  }
}

# Define the route table
resource "aws_route_table" "web_public_rt" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.gw.id
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "Public Subnet RT"
  }
}

# Assign the route table to the public Subnet
resource "aws_route_table_association" "web-public-rt" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.public_subnet_1.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.web_public_rt.id
}
```